# Relative Postion in a vector of n-minimum values in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

I would like to know how to compute a vector in Matlab that contains the relative position of the min value.
Just to explain better,since that i could be misunderstood,
I have this vector in Matlab and it contains this values  : 
Q=[10,15,11,18,90,21];
the first minimum is 10 and the relative position in that vector is 1, the second minimum is 11 and the relative position of the value in that vector is 3 and so on.
I need of a vector that contains the relative position of each value in order of mimimum,and then with the previous example:
Vector_result_position=[1,3,2,4,6,5].

Could you help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: This is simply the second output of `sort`... Let's see if there is a duplicate question there...

Comment: @knedlsepp - I couldn't find a suitable duplicate either so I decided to answer and will know for next time should something like this come along. (This is why I hate the StackOverflow search engine)

Comment: @rayryeng: I gave up. Guess it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @rayryeng Yes, the search engine definitely should be improved!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the second output of [`sort`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html).  The second output of `sort` tells you the position of where each number in the original unsorted array appears in its sorted result:

```
>> Q=[10,15,11,18,90,21];
>> [~, Vector_result_position] = sort(Q)

Vector_result_position =

     1     3     2     4     6     5
```

Therefore, element 10 in `Q` appears in the first position of the sorted result, element 15 in `Q` appears in the third position of the sorted result, element 11 in `Q` appears in the second position of the sorted result, etc.

Comment: Absolutely , Great.Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user3043636 - my pleasure.  I realized I answered quickly, so whenever you get around to it and/or whenever you are able, I wouldn't mind if you accepted my answer :) Thanks and good luck!